# Cascade update ConstraintViolationException on compound UniqueConstraint

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I'll simplify the example to get the idea across. My model looks like the following :
Projects have a ManyToMany relationship with Jobs. In order to create the join table, I created a ProjectJob entity that has an added column, "job_order". Project references an OneToMany link to a list of ProjectJob, with CascadeType.ALL.

I have a `UniqueConstraint` on ProjectJob that looks like this :

```
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"project_id", "job_order"}
```

Everything works like a charm unless I want to reorder the jobs in the project. Basically, I flip the orders around in my service and made sure that every ProjectJob was a unique job_order in the list, and then save the Project (since the ProjectJobs will be cascaded). Problems arise when JPA/Hibernate tries to flush the transaction since it tries to update "row by row", and obviously the UniqueConstraint is violated after the first update (even though the whole batch of updates would give a coherent state).

Weirdly enough, the service call happens inside a transaction, so I'm not sure why I get this error.
Is there any way to update the child members of a collection in a unique statement so that the UniqueConstraint gets checked after all the children have been updated, instead of getting triggered after the first one? If not, what solution is available for my use case?

Comment: Please show your mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use deferred constraints. Or you use `@ManyToMany @OrderColumn List<Job> jobs` in `Project` instead which handles all of this automatically for you.